# Minimum makespan for matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming, discrete-mathematics

Given a A*B, matrix it is required to partition it into m*n blocks in such a way that the maximum of sum of elements in each block is minimized.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220570172_Partitioning_a_Matrix_to_Minimize_the_Maximum_Cost

A matrix A = [aij] of nonnegative integers must be partitioned into p blocks (submatrices) corresponding to a set of vertical cuts parallel to the columns and a set of horizontal cuts parallel to the rows. With each block is associated a cost equal to the sum of its elements.  The problem is to finding a matrix partitioning that minimizes the cost of the block of maximum cost.

How can i implement this?

Comment: Ciuld you provide some examples?

Comment: Isn't the point of that article literally to explain how to do this?

Comment: @dmitry-bychenko Here is an example - http://4.1m.yt/Ihdb0Vf.png

Comment: This would appear to be part of an ongoing competition - https://www.codechef.com/SEPT16/problems/CHMTDV